# ESLint 7.1.0 Error: 'patterns' must be a non-empty string or an array of non-empty strings

Tags: javascript, eslint

I have just upgraded my ESLint to 7.1.0 and if I try to run it, I get this error:

```
Error: 'patterns' must be a non-empty string or an array of non-empty strings
```

I am providing the config file through the `-c` parameter, but I have no idea what is the problem, any ideas?

The error comes from the ESLint itself:

```
at ESLint.lintFiles (...)
```

Comment: are you using destructuring somewhere in your code? I so can you post the code?

Comment: @Yousaf You mean destructing in my JS code? Yes, I am, but the project has 1000+ files, so I can't really post it here...

Comment: It seems you might be executing ESLint on an empty list of files. How are you executing it and what pattern(s) are you using? https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/bcafd0f8508e19ab8087a35fac7b97fc4295df3e/lib/eslint/eslint.js#L502

Comment: @str I am executing it like this `-c build\jscodeinspection-framework\.eslintrc --rulesdir build\jscodeinspection-framework\rules src\main\js`

Comment: Can you try adding a trailing slash to the directory argument src\main\js\?

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this issue and I had an extra trailing space after my backslash. Look carefully and I had an extra space after the backslash in the before command.

Before -

```
eslint \ 
    Cool.js
```

After -

```
eslint \
    Cool.js
```